# CSS: new font breaking layout by aligning text to the top

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been working with Open Sans in a project for a while and we then decided to use a new font, and after  adding the new font the layout breaks everywhere and the text appears to be aligned to the top. Here are some screenshots for a simple text in an icon:

[image: Open Sans] [image: New Font] [image]

On the left is Open Sans, on the right is the new font. The inspect box of the new font is shown in the 3rd image.

Which css property should I change make the new font globally in the middle again?

EDIT: Here's another more visible Example with the inspect tool:

[image] [image]

The new font is on the right. Open Sans is on the left. There are no paddings or margins inside the element, it's just a span.

new font: https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/azo-sans

Comment: Please show us how that character is positioned at the moment. (put actual code into your question, not an image of it please - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) My guess is that flex will help you but without seeing the code I can't be sure.

Comment: I added new examples with the inspect tool that shows the positions. Neither flex nor line height help. And the element is a span without any margins or paddings in it, the little area beneath the 2 is caused by the new font

Comment: Then maybe its simply the layout of the new font!? How did you set the height of the span? You could use `height: fit-content` for the span

Comment: Could the css-property `vertical-align: middle;` help you?

Comment: the second span has a fixed line-height, but it doesn't matter as in the first example is just a bootstrap badge which stretches by changing the font. And vertical align doesn't do anything.

Comment: Your screenshot (the number 2 with the inspect tool) looks like there's a vertical offset of some kind. Which font is that - is it from google fonts where we could see and inspect it?

Comment: https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/azo-sans

Comment: To me this looks as if the container element (the circle simply isn't high enough for that font

Comment: What about apply `margin-bottom:-2px;` in all markups containing text

Comment: Please, please put relevant code into your question otherwise any answer is just a guess.